# Convergence of Mollifier in $W_0^{l,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I want to prove that for $u \in W_0^{l,p}(\Omega)$ we have convergence of mollifiers $u_\rho \rightarrow u$.

I appreciate that $u_\rho \rightarrow u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ so just need to show convergence of the derivatives, i.e.,

$$
D^\alpha u_\rho \rightarrow D^\alpha u
$$
in $L^p(\Omega)$.

My thoughts are to use a sequence $u_m \rightarrow u$ in $W_0^{l,p}(\Omega)$ with $u_m \in C_0^\infty (\Omega)$ with some form of triangle inequality, though I'm not exactly sure how. I know that $D^\alpha u_\rho = (D^\alpha u)_\rho$ in compact subsets of $\Omega$. This may help with $u_m$ compactly supported in $\Omega$.

Thanks.

Comment: By virtue of $u\in W^{l,p}$, $D^\alpha u \in L^p$ so you can use the first result 
$$ w_\rho \to w \text{ in } L^p$$
with $w = D^\alpha u$

Comment: @CalvinKhor but $(D^\alpha u)_\rho \neq D^\alpha u_\rho$ in general? Aren't you relying on this?

Comment: If two functions agree on any compact subset of $\Omega$ then they agree everywhere in $\Omega$, does this resolve the issue?

Comment: @CalvinKhor but the parameter $\rho$ is dependent on the compact subset $K$. That is, as $K$ increases in size, $\rho$ decreases.

Comment: I suppose you mean that the "starting value" of $\rho$ is something like $d(K,\partial \Omega)$? In which case, I'd like to know how you can make sense of $u_\rho \to u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, as opposed to in compact subsets?

Comment: @CalvinKhor my point is that to use your argument you require  the derivative of the mollifier equal to the mollifier of derivative. This can only be guaranteed for a fixed $\rho$ on a compact subset $K$. Your argument makes no use of the fact that $u \in W_0^{l,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: It should work for any $\rho<\rho_0$ for a fixed $\rho_0 = \rho_0(K) \sim d(K,\partial \Omega)$. My question is, how do you extend $u$ outside $\Omega$ to make sense of $u_\rho$ on the whole of $\Omega$?